# Register type with Unity to use constructor requiring parameter array

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, unity-container

Given the following constructor signature:

```
public MyClass(Class1 arg1, params Class2[] arg2)
```

How can I register MyClass with Unity passing in specific named types using an InjectionConstructor.

I've tried the following:

```
unityContainer.RegisterType<IMyClass, MyClass>(new InjectionConstructor(typeof(Class1), new ResolvedParameter<IClass2>("name1"), new ResolvedParameter<IClass2>("name2")))
```

but get an exception saying that there is no constructor with signature:

```
public MyClass(Class1 arg1, Class2 arg2, Class2 arg3)
```

I have got round the problem by overloading the MyClass constructor. Is there any way to do this without overloading  the constructor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why would you try and use an `InjectionConstructor` in the first place? Unity knows how to handle arrays out of the box.

The `params` keyword is just some syntactic sugar for the compiler. Under the cover `args2` is just a simple array.

```cs
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
  var container = new UnityContainer();
  // if you absolutely have to use an InjectionConstructor this should do the trick
  // container.RegisterType<IMyClass, MyClass>(
  //   new InjectionConstructor(typeof(Class1), typeof(Class2[])));
  container.RegisterType<IMyClass, MyClass>(
    new InjectionConstructor(typeof(Class1), typeof(Class2[])));
  container.RegisterType<Class2>("1");
  container.RegisterType<Class2>("2");
  container.RegisterType<Class2>("3");
  var myClass = container.Resolve<IMyClass>() as MyClass;
  Assert.IsNotNull(myClass);
  Assert.IsNotNull(myClass.Arg2);
  Assert.AreEqual(3, myClass.Arg2.Length);
}

interface IMyClass
{
}
class MyClass : IMyClass
{
  public Class1 Arg1 { get; set; }
  public Class2[] Arg2 { get; set; }
  public MyClass(Class1 arg1, params Class2[] arg2)
  {
    Arg1 = arg1;
    Arg2 = arg2;
  }
}
class Class1
{
}
class Class2
{
}
```

---

**Update**

If you are only using some of the named registrations you will have to use the `ResolvedArrayParameter`.

```cs
container.RegisterType<IMyClass, MyClass>(
  new InjectionConstructor(
    typeof(Class1),
    new ResolvedArrayParameter<Class2>(
      new ResolvedParameter<Class2>("1"), 
      new ResolvedParameter<Class2>("2"))));
```

Brrr! This is super ugly but it should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using an injection constructor because I have several implementations of IClass2 and I'm only passing some of them to the MyClass constructor. If there is a better way to do this please tell me!

Answer (score 1):

Since it seems to dislike the 'Class2' instances simply being listed directly, is it possible that explicitly setting them into an array (and therefore explicitly matching the constructor signature of `Class1, Class2[]`) would work:

```
unityContainer.RegisterType<IMyClass, MyClass>(new InjectionConstructor(typeof(Class1), new Class2[]{new ResolvedParameter<IClass2>("name1"), new ResolvedParameter<IClass2>("name2")}))
```

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work because the array is being declared of type Class2, but the objects it's being initialised with are of type ResolvedParameter. If I remove the object type from the array definition (i.e. new [] {...}) then it looks for a constructor taking in an array of ResolvedParameters!